# Does Spell Perfection double the bonus dice from Intensified Spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

The feat [Spell Perfection](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spell-perfection) reads

> Pick one spell which you have the ability to cast. Whenever you cast that spell you may apply any one metamagic feat you have to that spell without affecting its level or casting time, as long as the total modified level of the spell does not use a spell slot above 9th level. **In addition, if you have other feats which allow you to apply a set numerical bonus to any aspect of this spell (such as Spell Focus, Spell Penetration, Weapon Focus [ray], and so on), double the bonus granted by that feat when applied to this spell.**

Emphasis mine.

Would the double bonus apply to the extra dice provided by [Intensified Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/intensified-spell-metamagic) as long as your CL was high enough?

Normally the max is 5d6 with normal Intensify it would be 10d6. If Spell perfection would work on it it would be 15d6 max. That is if you have the CL to use all the dice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A " set numerical bonus " is exactly what it says, a set numerical bonus (+1 to save DC, +2 to hit with a ray, etc.). That is what gets doubled. Bonus die from any source are not a set numerical bonus, and do not get doubled. :-(

Comment: This.  Also Intensified Spell doesn't even give you a set number of dice, since it's level-based.

Comment: The feat does not add bonus dice.  It raises the cap on the number of dice, which technically *is* a set numerical bonus.

Comment: While it is set numerical, it isn't a "bonus" as defined in the glossary:  
"Bonuses are numerical values that are added to checks and statistical scores. Most bonuses have a type, and as a general rule, bonuses of the same type are not cumulative—only the greater bonus granted applies.

The important aspect of bonus types is that two bonuses of the same type don't generally stack. With the exception of dodge bonuses, most circumstance bonuses, and racial bonuses, only the better bonus of a given type works. Bonuses without a type always stack, unless they are from the same source."